# Distinguishing gluttony, greed and lust in their modern connotations?

Tags: philosophy

Of the seven deadly sins, gluttony, greed and lust have expanded in scope since they were first defined to point of being synonymous. Where originally they were limited to food/drink, riches and carnal pleasure, respectively, now either may apply to those targets. All three essentially boil down to a strong desire to experience a momentary high or possess an asset for its own sake.

How would one distinguish between the sins when the object is the same? How do the sins differ in other ways? This is relevant for determining how to assign souls damned to hell.

Comment: I would still usually associate lust with sexual desire (although it can be used for other things) and gluttony with food.  Greed does cover all of the others.  Also isn't your question basically 'how do we distinguish between three identical things?'.

Comment: There are many different conflicting interpretations of the "root cause" of the deadly sins. Philosophers in the middle ages considered Pride to be the root cause of the other sins. More modern writers have considered lust as the root cause. There are far too many ways of framing the sins to make this question answerable within the context of this site.

Comment: I question this premise. It is not true that they have become synonymous, not even on modern connotations. It is true that, linguistically, we can use figures of speech to compare the objects of one sin to the other, but that's semantics, not a true change in meaning. Case in point... if you call someone a "glutton", that person will not think about craving for riches, but rather food. Same if you call a person greedy or lustful... they will interpret the object of their sin as riches and carnal pleasure, respectively. If the general public can understand it, why not the jugdes of Hell?

Comment: This is not opinion based. Each of these words has a set definition that is not subjective.

Answer (score 8):

They all deal with some form of desire and the need to fill some gaping emptiness in one's life. However the dividing point is based on what you want to do with the thing you desire once you have it.

**Greed**

You want something, and then you want to keep it. Forever. Greed deals with hoarding simply to have things and many of them.

**Gluttony**

You want something, but you want to consume it. All of it. Gluttony is about the desire to consume things, to the point that one's hunger is never truly satisfied. This differs from greed in that, once something is acquired, it is otherwise destroyed or consumed with no consideration for the toll on either the body, the environment, or other people who may not have what they need.

**Lust**

You want something, but you want it solely for the physical pleasure that it brings you; furthermore, the selfish pleasuring of yourself is all you can think about. The desire for pleasure is all-consuming. Whether or not you end up keeping it is irrelevant, you just want it to make you feel good. Often this is pointed at another human, turning him or her into an object of pleasure. Sometimes, this isn't the case. Regardless, the focus with lust is for the end goal of self-pleasure without regard for the person or thing in question.

Answer (score 3):

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SevenDeadlySins

I'll be using that as a reference, but I'll also explain how they differ here. To quote that page, this is what each of those sins are defined as,

- Gluttony: Desire for Excess. In pop culture, this sin is almost always associated with overeating, which is a start, but theologically it applies to overconsumption of anything. Taking more than your share is a key part, as is wasting the excess. It has also been equated with any kind of addiction in modern times. The virtue to this vice is Temperance.
- Greed: Desire for Things. Often simply referred to as greed, but avarice includes spending money pointlessly as well as hoarding it. Greed is also very commonly associated with ambition. The virtue to this vice is Charity.
- Lust: Desire for Pleasure. It's the desire to know someone Biblically, but traditionally included all other sins of physical desire or luxury (such as drug addiction), not just sex. The virtue to this vice is Chastity. (Whose original definition did not mean "abstinence" but was closer to "monogamy".)

...

With definitions and antonyms out of the way, let's compare and contrast. All of these sins represent a desire of some kind that will lead a person to death (if left unchecked, thus "deadly"). However, each of these represent very different desires.

- Gluttony differs from Greed in that Gluttony resolves around a personal behavior.
- Gluttony differs from Lust in that Gluttony focuses on "more".
- Greed differs from Gluttony in that Greed revolves around a social behavior.
- Greed differs from Lust in that Greed is selfish.
- Lust differs from Gluttony in that Lust focuses on pleasure.
- Lust differs from Greed in that Lust is shareable.

Comment: Good list. The differences between the 3 are subtle but important.